# How can I add seconds to time series data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

So I have the following timestamps that belong to a TS in a pandas dataframe:

```
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
```

The original csv file has readings 60 readings for each minute passed, but the timestamp only has **hh:mm** (e.g. 13:23) and when I convert/parse the dates it just adds 00 to all the seconds entries. Is there any pandas functionality to add seconds? The motivation behind this is so that it will graph nicely in matplotlib. Currently I have 60 overlapping points for each minute, however I want the timestamps to be increasing e.g. 00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03, etc.

Comment: You should paste a minimal (!!!) working example of your code and data

Comment: If you are sure there are exactly 60 samples each minute, just create a timestamp object having date and time as zero and seconds as 1, 2, 3 .. then, just add the 2 in a loop

Comment: [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to 1s frequency might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

manually add seconds in there assuming they are sorted and increment is always 1 second:

```
df = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(2020,11,20,0,0)]*10)
df += pd.Series(pd.Timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(10))
```

```
0   2020-11-20 00:00:00
1   2020-11-20 00:00:01
2   2020-11-20 00:00:02
3   2020-11-20 00:00:03
4   2020-11-20 00:00:04
5   2020-11-20 00:00:05
6   2020-11-20 00:00:06
7   2020-11-20 00:00:07
8   2020-11-20 00:00:08
9   2020-11-20 00:00:09
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```